# IPHONE (in-app purchase): What do I have to do to get the prices in local currency

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am creating an application with 3 different languages: english, spanish and french. I have created in-app purchases in these 3 languages and have created users on itunes sandbox for these 3 stores: France, USA and Spain.

Before the user can click on the BUY button, even before the user logs in with his itunes username and password, I have to retrieve the prices of each product. This retrieval is done at the beginning of the application using this lines:

```
SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:IDobjects];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

In theory, this code should retrieve, among other things, the price of all objects in the local currency. By local currency I mean based on the language the user has its iPhone adjusted but in practice this code always retrieve the price in dollars?

What am I missing?

Another point is this: if the user is not logged in on iTunes, he/she will always see the message in English and the prices in dollars. After logging in, he will see the name of the in-app object in his language and the price in his currency, but the rest of the window will be in english. See next image:

[image]

thanks for any help.

Caixa is the object's name in spanish, 0,79€ is the correct price in local currency but the remainder of the window is in english!?  This window should be totally in the user's language!!!!!

Comment: I'm confused -- how do you think you can ever possibly find just **one** "currency based on the language"?!  Does English imply USD, Loonies, Pounds, Australian dollars, or...?  Does French imply Loonies (in Quebec), Euros (in France), Swiss Francs, or...?  Does Spanish imply Pesetas, USD (more than 40 million Latinos live here), Euros (in Spain), Chilean Pesos, or...? It seems you are requesting the impossible: surely currency is based on **country**, and _not_ on **language**!

Comment: Suppose the user is from Spain. He does not speaks english. His iPhone is adjusted for Spain and his language to Spanish. He runs my application and sees the message: this in-app object costs USD $0.99. He sees this message in english. As he doesn't speak english, he does not know what the message is telling you. He does not knows the price either, because he deals with euros. If the region is Spain and the language is Spanish, it must be a way to retrieve the price of the object in euros, not dollars and to show the messages from the store in spanish, not english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem vanished a few days ago. It appears it was something inside apple.

Answer (score 1):

How about using localized strings? So instead of @"Do you want to buy...", you would have something like: kPurchasePromptMessage, which will return a different string depending on the language used on the iphone.

Comment: This is what I came here to mention. Though I was wondering if you don't just specify a price in USD and then Apple handles the conversion somehow? The way he wants to do this now it seems like he would have to go and specify prices for each currency, which seems far too tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code from the Apple Docs:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Answer (score 0):

For That:

1. You have add Languages in Manage in-app purchase management for each bundleid
2. create test user For that country.
3. test your in-app purchase in application
4. enter your new test user for that country